# How to add dots to Highcharts legend and bars?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts, react-highcharts

Right now, my bar and legend looks like this. It is just a single color.

[image: My Bar]
[image: My legend ticker]

However, I am trying to add a pattern that does not exist within the default pattern fills. I want it to look like this.

[image: Wanted pattern fill for bar]

[image: Wanted pattern fill for legend]

I have looked quite a bit online, but can't seem to find anything to help me here. I have both an SVG and PNG for the pattern. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/pattern-fill.js"></script>

 series: [{
    showInLegend: true,
    type: 'bar',
    color: {
      pattern: {
        image: 'https://freesvg.org/img/dot-seamless-pattern.png',
        width:150,
        height:150
      }
    },
```

You can set an image as a pattern anywhere you can use a color.  I used a png here, but I would recommend an svg.

https://jsfiddle.net/blaird/2jwL13oc/1/